# Printf problem with Kernighan and Ritchie problem 1-17

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

In the code below (for problem 1-17 in "The C Programming Language", by Kernighan and Ritchie) why doesn't it print the longest line (at the bottom)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
#define LONGLINE 10

int getLineLength(char line[], int maxline){
  int i, c;

  for(i = 0; i< maxline-1 && (c = getchar() != EOF) && c != '\n'; i++)
    line[i] = c;

  if(c == '\n') {
      line[i] = c;
      i++;
  }

  line[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}



main() {
  int len;
  char line[MAXLINE];
  while((len = getLineLength(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    if(len > LONGLINE)
      printf("The line was over the maxlength\n\t %s", line);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is this in the book?Is it your solution to a problem or it is a code example in the book?

Comment: The original problem is Exercise 1-17 at the top of page 31 of the second edition.  My code is a verbatim copy from the "C Answer Book" (except for the fact that getLengthLine is different - it's actually the version from the original book and it's called getline)

Comment: Your indentation after the two loops is really confusing - you should indent only the loop body, not everything that follows it.

Comment: > by typing it.  ... You got it!  STDIN means run the program and 'type at it', use Ctrl-D to signal 'end-of-file'. The beauty of STDIN is that this means the program can read from many different sources without special processing to support each source. cat file | findMaxLine (read from a STDIN pipe) OR findMaxLine < file (open a file to the programs STDIN and 'redirect' the data into the program.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Both versions of the getLineLength function work.  Got it working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code:

```
(c = getchar() != EOF)
```

This will be evaluated as `(c = (getchar() != EOF))`, giving the wrong result. What you need is:

```
((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Answer (score 1):

This program reads from standard input, and prints that long message for lines longer 10 than characters. Lines end with '\n' (newline, ENTER). Input ends with EOF, if you feed a file, e.g. through a pipe, or CTRL-C, if you enter characters manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this works at all. `(c = getchar() != EOF)` is completely wrong for a start. `line[i] = c;` appears twice. And I think it's vulnerable to a buffer overflow in an edge case.

EDIT: An earlier answer that I can't see any more said that you seem to have your braces missing from the for loop.

Comment: line assingments are OK. Second one for newline is exclusive with first one.

Comment: Ah, your indentation was really confusing. Everything looks much better now, except for the `getchar()` bug as noted.